# A term that would define someone who'd prefer to inflict the most pain on someone they sought revenge on rather killing quickly

Tags: single-word-requests

This might contain spoilers on Infinity War. At the end, when Thanos completed the Gauntlet with all the stones, rather than killing him quickly with his axe, Thor decided to first make sure Thanos feels pain for all the thing he's done. What would you call Thor in this scenario?

It doesn't need to specifically cater to the description I gave, it could be something that would generally describe him, such as "Malevolent".

Comment: Hello, Martian, and welcome to EL&U. You are asking for a single word specific to this situation, and it may not exist. There are words which could be used, but they are more general, such as : cruel, vindictive,etc. Also, you need to provide a sample sentence with a blank in it to insert the target language.

Comment: Yes yes, I may need to edit my description (and I will), but those are mostly what I am looking for. General words close to what I described.

Comment: Just as a note, Thor *did* try to kill Thanos quickly with his axe . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford Thor has an _axe_? What? The hammer wasn't good enough?

Comment: @JasonBassford well, I would disagree. Thanos worded it perfectly, "You should have gone with the head." But, this isn't a movie review site.

Comment: And yes @Cascabel , watch Ragnarok and then Infinity War.

Answer (score 2):

The term [*sadist*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sadist) or [*sadism*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sadism) or [*sadistic*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sadistic) works for me.

> The deriving of pleasure from cruelty; thus, a person deriving pleasure from cruelty is a sadist. Adjectival form is *sadistic*.

I guess you could say that sadism is an extreme form of [schadenfreude](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/schadenfraude), which is the delight one feels in the misfortune or pain of someone else.

Comment: Sadism doesn't suggest that the victim of sadism is guilty of something.

Comment: I agree with KTM. However you are going at this in the right direction, Rhetorician. 
Schadenfroh is an adjective derived from Schadenfreude, so that may work as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could describe them as "cruel" or "inhumane." If you want to emphasize the revenge aspect, you could call them "vengeful." To incorporate the idea that they aren't satisfied with an eye for an eye, you could call them "implacably vengeful."